# Dynamically assign a column width to a winforms datagrid?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, width

I ve created columns of my datagrid using this,

```
   private void Receive_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Sender",typeof(string));
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Time",typeof(string));
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Message",typeof(string));
    }
```

- How can i dynamically assign a column width to a winforms datagrid?

Comment: Old question, I know, but are you using a DataGrid or a DataGridView? A DataGrid doesn't have a Columns property, assuming that's what dt is.  (Or is dt a DataTable?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for something line

```
DataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].Width = 75;
```

I Hope it help you.

In addition, you can set the AutoSizeMode of the column to obtain different behaviours automatically. For example, if you set it to ColumnHeader, then the cell width will be set to the best fit for showing the header text. You can get more info in this [Link](http://en.csharp-online.net/Presenting_Data_with_the_DataGridView_Control_in_.NET_2.0%E2%80%94Automatic_Column_Sizing).

Comment: The link (and your code) refers to the DataGridView control, not the DataGrid.

Comment: As you did, I assume we're talking about the DataGridView control because DataGrid hasn't a column property. In prevision of future missunderstanding, I retaged the question as DataGridView.

Comment: Thanks, but dt sounds more like DataTable to me.

Comment: you're right. I've also edited both the question and the answer to reflect this fact.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a suggestion:
If you know the length of your fields you can multiply their length by a constant value (max character width for example) to produce a dynamic width.