# C# Datatable column width

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Im having a problem with Datatable in C#. I have a `Datatable` with to columns. I want to manually set the size of the columns, how do I do this?

this is the code:

```
dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn culAvs = new DataColumn("Avskiping", typeof(string));
DataColumn culKota = new DataColumn("Kota", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add(culAvs);
dt.Columns.Add(culKota);
dataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: you should not work with the DataColumns of the System.Data.DataTable, that is the data container, kind of the results of the database query.

You should customize the size of the DataGrid columns, which is the UI control you use to render your data.

Comment: What do you mean by size like length of the text in this case ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175274/dynamically-assign-a-column-width-to-a-winforms-datagrid

Answer (score 10):

If you're talking about maximal length of data in columns, you might be interested in `DataColumn.MaxLength` property. But if you're talking about visual width of columns you should use `Width` property of a DataGrid's column: `dataGrid1.Columns[ ... ].Width = ...`

Comment: There is no Width property on the DataColumn object. - vb.net

Comment: @Sophie, please read carefully: "Width property of a DataGrid's column". We are talking about System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn class, which has lots of width-related properties like Width or MaxWidth. If you feel that my wording is confusing feel free to propose an edit, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The data table does not contain UI related properties, it's a data container.
You need to define the column visual properties on the data grid.

Comment: @Roi84 if you use ASP.net, you can set the data grid column's width by changing the itemstyle properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridcolumn.itemstyle.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this comment, i found how to change it: myDataGridView.Columns(0).Width = ....
this is how to set the width in pixel.
-vb.net